# using cutoff_frequency in elasticsearch with multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using `cutoff_frequency` in a `multi_match` query with multiple fields. Is it applied to every field individually? How does it work?

This is what my code looks like.

```
POST beta2_index/_search
{
  "_source": ["title"],
  "size": 20, 
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "test query",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "description"],
        "cutoff_frequency" : 0.1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`multi_match` query with option `best_fields` type (the default), is transformed into a `dis_max` query that wraps `match` queries, so `cutoff_frequency` option should be "forwarded" to every sub match queries.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-best-fields.

> The best_fields type generates a match query for each field and wraps
>   them in a dis_max query, to find the single best matching field.